# Rxjs ~6.4.0 in Angular 8. Problem with map

Tags: angular, rxjs

I updated my app to Angular 8 and there is new version of rxjs ~6.4.0. Now my .map fuction is not working and I have a mistake in VC

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I tried to import map by many ways

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

or this way

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The result the same.
Code below

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
const email = this.userInfo.email;
return this.routApi.checkUser(email).map(e => {
  this.tradeOperService.writeOperRoomFromResponse(e);
  return true;
}).catch((e) => {
  if (e.error === 'traderoom') {
    this.router.navigate(['registration']);
  }
  if (e.status === 500) {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe(
      suc => {
        this.tokenService.deleteToken();
        this.tradeOperService.deleteOperRoomInfo();
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      },
      err => {
        this.OperRoomService.deleteOperRoomInfo();
        this.tokenService.deleteToken();
      }
    );
  }
  return Observable.of(false);
});
```

The mistake if here

```
return this.routApi.checkUser(email).map(e => {
```

The same situation with "of" in the end of code

```
return Observable.of(false);
```

Comment: As per this site: https://update.angular.io/#5.0:8.0, you could try the following two commands which will attempt to automatically convert your RxJS code: npm (1) `install -g rxjs-tslint` (2)
`rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json`

Comment: There are numerous changes required for the new version (1) All imports are now from `rxjs` or `rxjs/operators` (2) pipe method is required to use any operators (3) `Observable.of` is now just `of` (4) `catch` is now `catchError`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It need to install rxjs-compat

Comment: Rxjs compat is not the solution, that is a workaround that adds to your bundle size and keeps you writing outdated, deprecated code in your app. You should use version 6 syntax to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pipe to chain operators now. change this:

```
return this.routApi.checkUser(email).map(e => {
```

to

```
return this.routApi.checkUser(email).pipe(
   map(e => {
   })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using / importing it correctly
    `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Can you provide details on implementation of

checkUser(email)

metod?

If it returns a promise, use from() to make Observable from it.

And correct way to import "of" is

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: checkUser(email: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('api/user/check-user/' + email);
  }

Comment: It need to install rxjs-compat